# Inno Setup conditional restart based on result of executable call

Tags: installation, inno-setup, restart

My Inno Setup script is used to install a driver. It runs my `InstallDriver.exe` after this file was copied during step `ssInstall`.

I need to ask the user to restart in some cases according to the value returned by `InstallDriver.exe`.

This means that I cannot put `InstallDriver.exe` in section `[Run]` because there's no way to monitor it's return value.

So I put it in function `CurStepChanged()` as follows:

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  TmpFileName, ExecStdout, msg: string;
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  if  (CurStep=ssPostInstall)  then
  begin 
    Log('CurStepChanged(ssPostInstall)');
    TmpFileName := ExpandConstant('{app}') + '\InstallDriver.exe';
    if Exec(TmpFileName, 'I', '',  SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then .......
```

However, I can't find a way to make my script restart at this stage.

I thought of using function `NeedRestart()` to monitor the output of the driver installer, but it is called earlier in the process.
Does it make sense to call the driver installer from within `NeedRestart()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NeedRestart` does not look like the right place to install anything. But it would work, as it's fortunately called only once. You will probably want to present a progress somehow though, as the wizard form is almost empty during a call to `NeedRestart`.

---

An alternative is to use [`AfterInstall` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptinstall) of the `InstallDriver.exe` or the driver binary itself (whichever is installed later).

```pascal
#define InstallDriverName "InstallDriver.exe"

[Files]
Source: "driver.sys"; DestDir: ".."
Source: "{#InstallDriverName}"; DestDir: "{app}"; AfterInstall: InstallDriver

[Code]
var
  NeedRestartFlag: Boolean;

const
  NeedRestartResultCode = 1;

procedure InstallDriver();
var
  InstallDriverPath: string;
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  Log('Installing driver');
  InstallDriverPath := ExpandConstant('{app}') + '\{#InstallDriverName}';
  if not Exec(InstallDriverPath, 'I', '',  SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
  begin
    Log('Failed to execute driver installation');
  end
    else
  begin
    Log(Format('Driver installation finished with code %d', [ResultCode]))
    if ResultCode = NeedRestartResultCode then
    begin
      Log('Need to restart to finish driver installation');
      NeedRestartFlag := True;
    end;
  end;
end;

function NeedRestart(): Boolean;
begin
  if NeedRestartFlag then
  begin
    Log('Need restart');
    Result := True;
  end
    else
  begin
    Log('Do not need restart');
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I don't see how I can display the 'Finish with restart' Wizard from within AfterInstall.

Comment: I mean that you install the driver from `AfterInstall` and remember the result, referring to it from the `NeedRestart`. See my edited answer.

Comment: Aha! Now I understand. Thanks.